# Adobe flash security update hangs Excel 2007 vba browser object

Tags: flash, excel, vba

Nowadays, Adobe flash plugin gives this message when trying to play flash content inside a VBA browser for excel 2007 -

"this document contains embedded content that may be harmful to your computer." with the choices "Do not allow content to play. (Recommended)" or "I recognize this content. Allow it to play."

That would be ok i guess, except that it hangs the excel session at that message and the only way to get out of it is to kill excel with the task manager.

Im not sure exactly when this update arrived, but now anything that uses flash in a VBA browser object is broken . Anyone else got this, or know how to get round it?

Answer (score 0):

Use tab or the arrow key to move through the options to choose "allow play", then enter.

Comment: The excel session hangs, he cant navigate